# Can't return object method name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the name of `delicious` and `love` method and then put it inside array `quotes`. I need to do this because the quotes will be displayed in a select box. I tried using `Function.name`. It works on `Say`, but when I use it on `delicious` and `love` I get empty string instead.

What is wrong here?

```
console.log('>>START')

function Say(name) {
    this.name = name
}

function Food(name) {
    this.name = name
}

Say.delicious = function(food) {
    if (!food) food = 'food'
    console.log('This '+food+' is delicious')
}
Say.love = function(food) {
    if (!food) food = 'food'
    console.log('I love '+food)
}

var pizza = new Food('Pizza')
var donut = new Food('Donut')
var quotes = [Say.delicious.name, Say.love.name]

Say.delicious(donut.name) // This Donut is delicious
Say.love(pizza.name) // I love Pizza
console.log(quotes) // ["",""]
console.log(Say.name) // Say
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because function `delicious` is actually an anonymous function which has a reference of `Say.delicious`, if i understand it correctly.

You could make it a named function by specifying it like so:

```
Say.delicious = function delicious(food) {
    if (!food) food = 'food'
    console.log('This '+food+' is delicious')
}
```

```js
console.log('>>START')

function Say(name) {
    this.name = name
}

function Food(name) {
    this.name = name
}

Say.delicious = function delicious(food) {
    if (!food) food = 'food'
    console.log('This '+food+' is delicious')
}
Say.love = function love(food) {
    if (!food) food = 'food'
    console.log('I love '+food)
}

var pizza = new Food('Pizza')
var donut = new Food('Donut')
var quotes = [Say.delicious.name, Say.love.name]

Say.delicious(donut.name) // This Donut is delicious
Say.love(pizza.name) // I love Pizza
console.log(quotes) // ["",""]
console.log(Say.name) // Say
```